# R bigrquery: Exceeded rate limits

Tags: r, google-bigquery, tidyverse, dbi, bigrquery

I am trying to download a BigQuery data set from Google Cloud Platform into R workspace in order to analyze it, using the following code:

```
library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)


con = dbConnect(
  bigquery(),
  project = "bigquery-public-data",
  dataset = "new_york_citibike",
  billing = "maanan-bigquery-in-r"
)

bigrquery::bq_auth()

my_db_pointer = tbl(con, "citibike_trips")

glimpse(my_db_pointer)

count(my_db_pointer)

selected  =  select(my_db_pointer, everything()) %>% collect()
```

However, when I try to run the last line in order to download the data, it returns the following error:

```
Complete
Billed: 0 B
Downloading first chunk of data.
Received 55,308 rows in the first chunk.
Downloading the remaining 58,882,407 rows in 1420 chunks of (up to) 41,481 rows.
Downloading data [=====>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]   6% ETA: 19m
Error in `signal_reason()`:
! Exceeded rate limits: Your project:453562790213 exceeded quota for tabledata.list bytes per second per project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors [rateLimitExceeded] 
ℹ Try increasing the `page_size` value of `bq_table_download()`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I would be very grateful if someone can help me fix this error and download the data? I need to analyze the data set. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation link about [rateLimitExceeded](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages), it looks like you break the threshold of [query jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs).

Please consider the following:

- Check if your project `bigquery api` have setup limits and quotas that you might be breaking when performing the operation. To see your current quotas and limits please go to *IAM & Admin > Quotas > Quotas for project "projectid"* > bigquery.google.apis.com
- As your chunks are about `55,308 rows` per chunk of `58,882,407 rows` it appears you are trying to download way more data that it allows and you might be hitting the following limits: `Query/script execution-time limit`, `Maximum response size`,  `Maximum row size`.
- Verify if [table constraints](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables) are not reached. Specially the one about `operations per day`.
- Check the amount of columns you row have. There is a limit of 10,000 columns.
- Consider checking all the rest of quota limits specified on [query jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs).
- Reducing the scope of your select or reduce the size of your chunks. Million records tables of  everything its truly needed?. You can perform something like this:

  ```
  library(bigrquery)

  # authenticate
  # use if notebook is outside gcp
  #bigrquery::bq_auth(path = '/Users/me/restofthepath/bigquery- credentials.json')

  bq_table_download("my-project-id.dataset-id.table", page_size = 100)
  ```

  For additionals details about this function, check [bq_table_download](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/bq_table_download.html)

Comment: Hello @Saïd Maanan, were you able to address your issue?

Comment: Hi @Betjens, I ended up download part of the data as zip file. Besides this issue my laptops's specs are too limited for a data set of this size. But thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi there. I am also getting this error. After looking around a while and finding notices saying you can increase your quota, I noticed I'm not even close to the limit.

I noticed that, even at peak usage, we only reached around 40% of the quota. Why would we get this error if the limit is not being reached?